# In Elastic Index Templates, how to Map any Field to @timestamp?

Tags: elasticsearch, unix-timestamp

I want to create a data stream on elastic. In order to do so, I need to first create an index template. All index templates expect to have a @timestamp field. I only have a field called 'ts' with floats containing seconds to epoch. I want to use it for the @timestamp field but I am having trouble finding a way to specify that @timestamp will not be its own field, it will instead take data from 'ts' and treat the data as dates. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I tried to omit the @timestamp field entirely in the index template. The issue is the elastic automatically generates the @timestamp field if the user does not provide it. In the end, I was unable to input documents in the data stream since the documents do not include the @timestamp field.

[image]

Comment: Check the following https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors